# Library version differences between linux distros

Tags: linux, version, linux-distro

I'm debugging a program that runs fine on one machine running (fill in the blank with some linux distro and version) but acts flaky on another machine running (different distro/version).

A helpful clue would be to see a side-by-side list of versions of all the major libraries provided by each distro - Qt, boost, libpng, fftw3, etc. including all the obscure ones.    We're not concerned about upgrades to libraries that may have happened since (for now).

Today it's Red Hat 5 vs. Fedora 13, but in the past I've wanted to compare Fedora and Ubuntu, and in the future any combination of major distros and versions, from at least four years ago up to last week, could come up.  I'm hunting for a general way to find these library version differences.

A web app that lets one pick any two distros and get a list would be awesome.  Does such a thing exist?    (If not, there's an idea for some entrepreneur.)

Note: I don't have access to one of the machines, so sorting and comparing 'ls /usr/lib' is out.

Comment: I am aware of the distrowatch site, and it seems like the info is available in there, but would take a lot of digging.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I know about would definitely be this one (the name rpmfind.net should give away it's RPM centric so Ubuntu will probably not be listed): http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/